# Thread Memory Management - Job Schedular

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, memory-management

i have a Memory issue in my application. i'm using Jobschedular as my thread class. While running my Java application memory keeps on increasing. Below is my Code. i have tried with system.gc & run time garbage collection also there is no use of it. pls let me know what is wrong on the below thread class.

```
public class JobScheduler
    implements Runnable
{
    private class JobNode
    {

        public Runnable job;
        public Date executeAt;
        public long interval;
        public int count;

        private JobNode()
        {
        }

    }


    public JobScheduler()
    {
        dlock = new DaemonLock();
        jobs = new Vector();
        Thread js = new Thread(this);
        js.setDaemon(true);
        js.start();
    }

    private synchronized void addJob(JobNode job)
    {
        dlock.acquire();
        jobs.addElement(job);
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void relancerJOBsEnAttente()
    {
        notify();
    }

    private synchronized void deleteJob(Runnable job)
    {
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            if(i >= jobs.size())
                break;
            if(((JobNode)jobs.elementAt(i)).job.equals(job))
            {
                jobs.removeElementAt(i);
                dlock.release();
                break;
            }
            i++;
        } while(true);
    }

    private JobNode updateJobNode(JobNode jn)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(jn.executeAt);
        if(jn.interval == -4L)
        {
            SchedulerAction sa = (SchedulerAction)jn.job;
            MaDate md = MaDate.getPlusPetiteDate(sa.getElementScheduler().getListDaysOfWeek());
            if(md == null)
                jn.count = 1;
            else
                jn.executeAt = new Date(getNextDateMD(md));
        } else
        if(jn.interval == -3L)
        {
            //System.out.println("::: calculate WD :::");
            SchedulerAction sa = (SchedulerAction)jn.job;
            jn.executeAt = new Date(getNextDateWD(jn.executeAt, sa.getElementScheduler().getListDaysOfWeek(), sa.getElementScheduler().getListWeeksOfMonth()));
        } else
        if(jn.interval == -1L)
        {
            cal.add(2, 1);
            jn.executeAt = cal.getTime();
        } else
        if(jn.interval == -2L)
        {
            cal.add(1, 1);
            jn.executeAt = cal.getTime();
        } else
        {
            for(jn.executeAt = new Date(jn.executeAt.getTime() + jn.interval);
                               jn.executeAt.getTime() < (new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())).getTime();
                               jn.executeAt = new Date(jn.executeAt.getTime() + jn.interval));
        }
        jn.count = jn.count != -1 ? jn.count - 1 : -1;
        return jn.count == 0 ? null : jn;
    }

    private synchronized long runJobs()
    {
        long minDiff = 0x7fffffffffffffffL;
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JobNode jn = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < jobs.size();)
        {
            jn = (JobNode)jobs.elementAt(i);
            if(jn.executeAt.getTime() <= now)
            {
                Thread jt = new Thread(jn.job);
                jt.setDaemon(false);
                SchedulerAction act = (SchedulerAction)jn.job;
                if(act.getElementScheduler().isWorking())
                {
                    act.getElementScheduler().getLogger().warn("########## NEXT SCHEDULE EXECUTION IMPOSSIBLE, TASK IS WORKING #######");
                    act.getElementScheduler().getLogger().warn("########## (AT TIME : " + new Date(jn.executeAt.getTime()) + ") #######");
                    act.getElementScheduler().getLogger().warn("########## EXTRACTION TAKE TO MUCH TIME OR PHAMTOM NOT RUNNING #######");
                } else
                {
                    act.reactiverCondition();
                    act.getElementScheduler().setProgressBarStart();
                    ParametersStaticsLogsAndStatistics.addLog("SCHEDULER", "Information", Loader_Parameters_JBLoader.RESOURCES.getString("SCHED_START") + " << " + act.getElementScheduler().getTaskName() + " >> " + Loader_Parameters_JBLoader.RESOURCES.getString("SCHED_START_AT") + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), "");
                    ParametersStaticsScheduler.listJobsWorking.add(act);
                    if(act.getElementScheduler().getFrequencyType().equals(Loader_Parameters_JBLoader.RESOURCES.getString("SCHED_FREQ_TYPE_IMM")))
                    {
                        act.getElementScheduler().setStartTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        JPScheduler.tableScheduler.updateUI();
                    }
                    act.getElementScheduler().initNbTables();
                    act.getElementScheduler().setWorking(true);
                    System.out.println("*****************************************");
                    System.out.println("START du task " + act.getElementScheduler().getTaskName());
                    System.out.println("*****************************************");
                    act.getElementScheduler().getLogger().info("# Commit count : " + GENERAL.getCommitCount());
                    if(act.getElementScheduler().getProperties().isUseextractor())
                        JPTreeTable.setEnableTreeTable(act.getElementScheduler().getPackageSelected().getTreeTable(), false);
                    if(act.getElementScheduler().getFrequencyType().equals(Loader_Parameters_JBLoader.RESOURCES.getString("SCHED_FREQ_TYPE_MD")))
                    {
                        MaDate temp = MaDate.getPlusPetiteDate(act.getElementScheduler().getListDaysOfWeek());
                        if(temp != null)
                            act.getElementScheduler().getListDaysOfWeek().remove(temp);
                    }
                    System.gc();
                    jt.start();
                }

                if(updateJobNode(jn) == null)
                {
                    jobs.removeElementAt(i);
                    dlock.release();
                } else
                {
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTimeInMillis(jn.executeAt.getTime());
                    //
                    act.getElementScheduler().setCompletedTime(new Timestamp(jn.executeAt.getTime()));
                    //System.out.println("next datetime execute : " + act.getElementScheduler().getCompletedTime());
                }
            } else
            {
                long diff = jn.executeAt.getTime() - now;
                minDiff = Math.min(diff, minDiff);
                i++;
            }
        }

        return minDiff;
    }

    public synchronized void run()
    {
        do
        {
            long waitTime = runJobs();
            try
            {
                wait(waitTime);
            }
            catch(Exception e) { }
        } while(true);
    }

    public void execute(Runnable job)
    {
        executeIn(job, 0L);
    }

    public void executeIn(Runnable job, long millis)
    {
        executeInAndRepeat(job, millis, 1000L, 1);
    }

    public void executeInAndRepeat(Runnable job, long millis, long repeat)
    {
        executeInAndRepeat(job, millis, repeat, -1);
    }

    public void executeInAndRepeat(Runnable job, long millis, long repeat, int count)
    {
        Date when = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + millis);
        executeAtAndRepeat(job, when, repeat, count);
    }

    public void executeAt(Runnable job, Date when)
    {
        executeAtAndRepeat(job, when, 1000L, 1);
    }

    public void executeAtAndRepeat(Runnable job, Date when, long repeat)
    {
        executeAtAndRepeat(job, when, repeat, -1);
    }

    public void executeAtAndRepeat(Runnable job, Date when, long repeat, int count)
    {
        JobNode jn = new JobNode();
        jn.job = job;
        jn.executeAt = when;
        jn.interval = repeat;
        jn.count = count;
        addJob(jn);
    }

    public void executeAtAndRepeatWD(Runnable job, long time, List daysOfWeek, List weekOfMonth)
    {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTimeInMillis(time);

        //test
        //if (

        Date date = null;
//        GregorianCalendar _tmp = gc;
        int dow = gc.get(7);
//        System.out.println("le premier dow est : " + dow);
//        GregorianCalendar _tmp1 = gc;
        int wom = gc.get(4);
//        System.out.println("le premier wom est : " + wom);
        //
        boolean existe = false;
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            //
            if(i >= weekOfMonth.size())
                break;
//            System.out.println("week du mois : " + (String)weekOfMonth.get(i));
//            System.out.println("index du wom : " + ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexWOM((String)weekOfMonth.get(i)));
//            System.out.println("alors compararer wom et parameter avant");
            if(wom == ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexWOM((String)weekOfMonth.get(i)))
            {
                existe = true;
                break;
            }
            if ( ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexWOM((String)weekOfMonth.get(i)) == 1 && wom == 0){
                existe = true;
                break;
            }

            i++;
        } while(true);
//        System.out.println("le wom final : " + wom);

        if(!existe)
        {
            date = new Date(getNextDateWD(gc.getTime(), daysOfWeek, weekOfMonth));
//            System.out.println("date est : " + date);
        } else
        {
            existe = false;
            i = 0;
            do
            {
//                System.out.println("second do...");
                if(i >= daysOfWeek.size())
                    break;
                if(dow == ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexDOW((String)daysOfWeek.get(i)))
                {
                    existe = true;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            } while(true);
            //
//            System.out.println("le dow est : " + dow);
            if(!existe)
                date = new Date(getNextDateWD(gc.getTime(), daysOfWeek, weekOfMonth));
            else
                date = gc.getTime();
            //
//            System.out.println("date2 est : " + date);
        }
        GregorianCalendar tempo = new GregorianCalendar();
        tempo.setTime(date);
//        GregorianCalendar _tmp2 = tempo;
//        GregorianCalendar _tmp3 = gc;
        tempo.set(10, gc.get(10));
//        GregorianCalendar _tmp4 = tempo;
//        GregorianCalendar _tmp5 = gc;
        tempo.set(12, gc.get(12));
        ((SchedulerAction)job).getElementScheduler().setStartTime(new Timestamp(tempo.getTimeInMillis()));
//        System.out.println("l'executer a : " + tempo.getTime());
        executeAtAndRepeat(job, tempo.getTime(), -3L, -1);
    }

    public void executeAtAndRepeatMD(Runnable job, long time, List dateSelected)
    {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTimeInMillis(time);
        MaDate temp = MaDate.getPlusPetiteDate(dateSelected);
        long t = getNextDateMD(temp);
        Date date = new Date(t);
        GregorianCalendar gc_ = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc_.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        gc_.set(10, gc.get(10));
        gc_.set(12, gc.get(12));
        executeAtAndRepeat(job, new Date(gc_.getTimeInMillis()), -4L, -1);
    }

    public long getNextDateWD(Date executeAt, List daysOfWeek, List weekOfMonth)
    {
        GregorianCalendar dAmain = new GregorianCalendar();
        dAmain.setTimeInMillis(executeAt.getTime());
        GregorianCalendar dAc = new GregorianCalendar();
        dAc.setTimeInMillis(dAmain.getTimeInMillis());
        //
        //System.out.println("dAmain : " + dAmain.getTime());
        //System.out.println("dAc : " + dAc.getTime());
        GregorianCalendar dMin = null;
        GregorianCalendar dT = null;

        //x mise a jour du bug index = 0 en EUROPE et index = 1 en USA
        int ws = 0;
        boolean again = false;

        //boucler 2 fois, si pas trouver au premier passage, sinon passer au mois suivant
      for ( int ind = 0; ind <= 1; ind++ ){
          //Parcourir de fisrt à last sélectionnés
          for ( int i = 0; i < weekOfMonth.size(); /*i++*/ ){

              //correction bug!
              if ( dAc.get(dAc.WEEK_OF_MONTH) == 0 &&
                   ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexWOM ( (String)weekOfMonth.get(i) ) == 1 &&
                   !again ){
                  //rien faire
                  again = true;
                  ws = 0;
              }
              else{
                  again = false;
                  ws = ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexWOM ( (String)weekOfMonth.get(i) );
              }


              //Parcourir les jours de la semaine
              for ( int j = 0; j < daysOfWeek.size(); j++ ){
                  //obtenir la date pour un jour de la semaine donné et
                  //un weekend du mois donné
//                  System.out.println("getDateWD ( " + dAc.getTime() + ", " + daysOfWeek.get(j) + ", " + weekOfMonth.get(i));
                  dT = getDateWD(dAc, (String)daysOfWeek.get(j), ws);
          //if ( dT != null )System.out.println ( "dT OBTENUE : " + dT.getTime() );
                  //else System.out.println("dT found is null!!!");
                  //
                  if (dT != null ){
                      // la date Tempo est > date actuelle
              //System.out.println ( "  - compara dT.compare(dAmain) > 0  : " + dT.compareTo(dAmain));
                      if ( dT.compareTo(dAmain) > 0 ){
                          //garder la plus petite date
                          if ( dMin == null ){
                              //System.out.println("dMin est null alors devien dT '"+dT+"'" );
                             //
                             dMin = dT;
                          }
                          else if ( dMin.compareTo( dT ) > 0 ){
                              //
                              //System.out.println("dMin > dT ===> dMin = " + dT.getTime());
                              dMin = dT;

                          }
                      }
                  }
              }//for parcours jours de la semaine
              if ( again ) {}
              else{ i++; }
          }//For parcours weeks de la semaine

          //la date minimale trouve est différente que la date Actuelle
          if ( dMin != null ){
              if ( dMin.compareTo ( dAmain ) > 0  ) {
                  //mettre ajour jeure et minute e seconde pour le min (si jamis)
                  dMin.set(Calendar.HOUR, dAmain.get(Calendar.HOUR));
                  dMin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dAmain.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                  dMin.set(Calendar.SECOND, dAmain.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                  break;
              }
          }
          //si non continuer au mois suivant
          dAc.set(dAc.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
          dAc.add(dAc.MONTH, 1);

      }


        //System.out.println("Dmin found in 'getNextDateWD' --> " + dMin.getTime());
        return dMin.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    /*******************************
   * getDateWD
   *******************************/
  public GregorianCalendar getDateWD(GregorianCalendar dA, String dow, int wom){
      //
      GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
      //gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+01:00"));
//      gc.set(gc.ZONE_OFFSET);

      try{
          gc.setTimeInMillis(dA.getTimeInMillis());
          //gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+01:00"));
          //
          int index = wom;
//          System.out.println("index = " + index);

//          if ( index == ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexWOM(ParametersStaticsScheduler.LAST) ){
//              System.out.println("last..... : " + gc.getActualMaximum(gc.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
//              index = gc.getActualMaximum(gc.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
//          }
//          else if ( gc.get(gc.WEEK_OF_MONTH ) == 0 ){
//          }

//          System.out.println("ajouter au WEEK_OF MONT(" + (index - gc.get(gc.WEEK_OF_MONTH )) );
          gc.add ( gc.WEEK_OF_MONTH, index - gc.get(gc.WEEK_OF_MONTH ) );
//          System.out.println("foutre le DAY_OF_WEEk a : " + ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexDOW ( dow ));
          gc.set ( gc.DAY_OF_WEEK, ParametersStaticsScheduler.getIndexDOW ( dow ) );

      }catch(Exception e){
          return null;
      }
      return gc;
  }


    public long getNextDateMD(MaDate dateSelected)
    {
        GregorianCalendar dA = new GregorianCalendar();
        dA.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(dateSelected == null)
        {
            return 0L;
        } else
        {
            dA.set(1, dateSelected.getYear());
            dA.set(2, dateSelected.getMonth());
            dA.set(5, dateSelected.getDay());
            return dA.getTimeInMillis();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void deleteFromWaitingList(TElement_Scheduler tes)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i = jobs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                SchedulerAction act = (SchedulerAction)((JobNode)jobs.get(i)).job;
                if(tes.getTaskId() == act.getElementScheduler().getTaskId())
                {
                    jobs.removeElementAt(i);
                    dlock.release();
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception e : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public synchronized void supendsAll()
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i = jobs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                jobs.removeElementAt(i);
                dlock.release();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) { }
    }

    public void executeAtNextDOW(Runnable job, Date when, int DOW)
    {
        Calendar target = Calendar.getInstance();
        target.setTime(when);
        for(; target.get(7) != DOW; target.add(5, 1));
        executeAt(job, target.getTime());
    }

    public void configureBackup(Runnable job)
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        executeAtNextDOW(job, now.getTime(), 1);
    }

    public static final int ONCE = 1;
    public static final int FOREVER = -1;
    public static final long HOURLY = 0x36ee80L;
    public static final long DAILY = 0x5265c00L;
    public static final long WEEKLY = 0x240c8400L;
    public static final long MONTHLY = -1L;
    public static final long YEARLY = -2L;
    public static final int WEEKLY_OPTION = -3;
    public static final int MONTHLY_OPTION = -4;
    private DaemonLock dlock;
    private Vector jobs;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the jobs vector keeps growing. There is a `deleteJob` method but that method is not used.

Comment: Hi VanOekel, You are correct. The Job Vector keeps on increasing the memory. But i have deleteJob method in my code.

Answer (score 0):

We can't figure out what is causing the memory leak by just looking at code like this. So what you really need to do are the followings:

**First:** Track your application while that memory leak using `vesualVM`, generate a heap dump and thread dump, then analyze the heap, you will find the exact objects that takes that much of memory, and the thread dump will show you where is you code currently executing, after that you'll be able to fix your code.

**Second:** you need to look at the `JVM` memory parameter, it will help you to optimize your application

**1)** This parameters will not avoid the memory leak but its good to know:

```
-Xmx2048m -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms1024m -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
```

**2)** this parameter will speed up the `GC` so `GC` will have more proportionality to clean up you memory

```
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize=614m -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
```

**3)** never ever use `System.gc`, use `CMS` garbage collector.

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Comment: Note that using CMS will increase the memory footprint. If latency is not an issue, use the parallell gc instead (the default on most machines) or maybe the G1 collector. I do concur in not calling System.gc(). If you have a memory leak problem, calling the gc will not help.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for ur reply. i dont have any memory leak in my application. When i run the runJobs() method i am getting the memory increased.

Comment: Dear Salah, i have tracked my application & the problem is in runJob() method only. Any idea on this method.